# Advanced Save Options missing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, character-encoding, visual-studio-2017

In VS2015 I would select File -> "Advanced Save Options...", where I could pick the encoding I wanted, e.g. UTF-8.

In VS2017, this option is no longer in the File menu.

How can I save files with a specific encoding in VS2017?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[From Visual Studio Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/8290/file-advanced-save-options-option-is-missed.html):

> Advanced Save Options... has been moved due to uncommon use.

You can still access the functionality through File-> Save As -> then clicking the down arrow on the Save button and clicking "Save With Encoding..."

[image: Save With Encoding...]

You can also add it back to the File menu through Tools->Customize->Commands if you want to.

[image: add advanced save option to file menu]

Comment: Also, depending on your project type. Debug -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character set: Not set / Use Unicode Character Set / Use Multi-Byte Character Set / Inherit. Would that setting not do the same?

Comment: @T.S he was asking about Advanced Save Options

Answer (score 6):

Turns out there is a caret in the Save-button after you select "Save As...", there you can select "Save with encoding".