# use PowerShell to save file in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, automation, character-encoding

Using Powershell from Package Manager Console I can [open and close file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426592/240564):

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.OpenFile”, $file)
$DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.Close”)
```

But when I try to save it:

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.Save”, $file)
```

or

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.Save”)
```

I get error:

> PM> $DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.Save”) Command "File.Save" is not valid.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $DTE.ExecuteCommand(“File.Save”)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

How I can save it?

Actually I want to save it in other encoding:

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom

Comment: @SergeyVlasov, yes I do it manually in VS, I just want to automate this

Comment: The answers from the link above mention Fix File Encoding and editorconfig that remove the need to do it manually.

Comment: @SergeyVlasov, I don't see in menu "Advanced save options"

Comment: [Advanced Save Options missing in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832068/advanced-save-options-missing-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: @SergeyVlasov, I added Advanced Save Option, but anyway I should choose encoding for each file separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the file with

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveSelectedItems")
```

There is also

```
$DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll")
```

If you're doing this only to change the file's encoding however, I would suggest simply running the following PowerShell code that doesn't require `$DTE` and Visual Studio at all.

```
$content = Get-Content -Path $file -Encoding String
Set-Content -Value $content -Path $file -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: yes, it works. But how I can Save As... and choose encoding?

I tried to use this PowerShell code (in your answer second part), but it didn't work for me, because I need UTF-8 without signature.

But VS works fine if I do it manually.

Comment: I coudln't find a way to open the encoding menu through `ExecuteCommand`, however for a PowerShell solution you can see this other SO question https://stackoverflow.com/q/5596982/446515

Comment: got list of commands by `$DTE.Commands File`, this command `File.SaveSelectedItemsAs` exists, but 'IsAvalable = false'. The same with 'File.AdvancedSaveOptions`